# Creating a one dimensional numpy array with specific predifined orderings of elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code which aims to simulate the motion of the planets. I want to initialise an initial velocity and takes `self.p` from a list in the first pass to initialise the velocity. `self.p` is of the form `[5.79e10,0]` and represents the planets initial distance from the sun along the initialisation axis.

```
self.v=np.array([0,(math.sqrt((6.673e-11)*(1.989e30)/(np.linalg.norm(self.p))))])
print(self.v)
```

for which I am expecting to get an initial velocity vector with no x component and the velocity entirely in the y direction. However this returns:

```
[5.79e+10 0.00e+00]
[1.08e+11 0.00e+00]
[1.496e+11 0.000e+00]
[2.28e+11 0.00e+00]
```

which is in exactly the opposite order to the way I thought I created the numpy array. Please could someone explain to me why this is happening and how I can avoid this for future reference?

Comment: Would make it easier if you post some more info, like what `self.p` is

Comment: do runing the line np.array([0,(math.sqrt((6.673e-11)*(1.989e30)/(np.linalg.norm([5.79e10,0]))))])  alone return the expected value(for me it do). if so your bug is elswere.